# How to get lower value by closest index?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, dynamic-programming, treemap

I have the following list values:

```
List<Integer> days = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
List<Integer> temperatures = List.of(4, 5, 7, 3, 6, 9, 7, 2, 5, 3);
```

Each day has the corresponding temp value on the given order (1st day is 4, 2dn day is 5, ...). I also have search values for days:

```
List<Integer> searchDays = List.of(6, 5, 4);
```

I am trying to find the nearest lower value for each searchDay values. For example:

```
6 --> 6th day value is 9 degree. 
The nearest lower value of it 6 that is on the 5th day.
```

I used the following approaches to solve the problem, but have the mentioned problem during these:

1. NavigableMap: I can just get the lower value in the map. For example, in the example above, I get 8, instead of 6. But I need to get the nearest lower value instead of a lower (value-1) value.
2. I used sliding window and solved the problem, but I needed to use inner loop with `O(n^2)`. I need to find a better solution with less time complexity.
3. I tried to use `HashMap<day, temperature>`, but it does not make any sense I think and probably I would need to use 2 loop.

So, how can I solve this problem with a better time complexity than `O(n^2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question correctly.

If you really need to search for the nearest lower temperature in the range `[i - 1, i + 1]` (between 'neighbour' days, closest indices), where `i` is the current day index:

**Using a HashMap**:

```
private int getLowerTemperature(Map<Integer, Integer> temperatures, int searchDay) {
        int dayIndex = searchDay - 1;

        int previousDayTemp = temperatures.getOrDefault(dayIndex - 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        int currentDayTemp = temperatures.getOrDefault(dayIndex, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        int nextDayTemp = temperatures.getOrDefault(dayIndex + 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        return Math.min(previousDayTemp, Math.min(currentDayTemp, nextDayTemp));
    }
```

***Complexities***:
O(1) - space,
O(1) - time

**Using an ArrayList**:

```
    private int getLowerTemperature(List<Integer> temperatures, int searchDay) {
        int dayIndex = searchDay - 1;
        if (temperatures.size() < 2 || dayIndex > temperatures.size()) {
            return temperatures.get(0);
        }

        int currentDayTemp = temperatures.get(dayIndex);
        // corner cases
        if (dayIndex == 0) {
            return Math.min(currentDayTemp, temperatures.get(dayIndex + 1));
        }
        if (dayIndex == temperatures.size() - 1) {
            return Math.min(temperatures.get(dayIndex - 1), currentDayTemp);
        }

        int previousDayTemp = temperatures.get(dayIndex - 1);
        int nextDayTemp = temperatures.get(dayIndex + 1);

        return Math.min(previousDayTemp, Math.min(currentDayTemp, nextDayTemp));
    }
```

Actually here you don't need `List<Integer> days` if every index of `List<Integer> temperatures` corresponds to its day.

***Complexities***:
O(1) - space,
O(1) - time